# Babel 5.8.38 ignore await in Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await, babeljs

I have problem with Babel 5.8.38 and await in Node.js
My code seems like that:

```
/**
 * Imports
 */
import {signature} from '../core/antpool';
import log from '../core/logging';
import config from '../config';
import {sendLog as sendEmailLog, EmailTemplate} from '../core/email';
import {rethinkdb, Decorators as DBDecorators} from '../core/db';
import request from 'request';

const tables = {
    AntpoolAccount: 'CronAntpoolAccount'
};

class Antpool {

    @DBDecorators.table(tables.AntpoolAccount)
    static async account(coin) {
        var nonce = Date.now();
        request.post({
            url: config.antpool.baseUrl + '/api/account.htm',
            json: true,
            form: {
                key: config.antpool.key,
                nonce: nonce,
                signature: signature(nonce),
                coin: coin
            }
        }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err || httpResponse.statusCode != 201) {
                log.error(err, '[CRON][Antpool][Account] Connection problem');
                sendEmailLog(EmailTemplate.LOG, {
                    message: '[CRON][Antpool][Account] Connection problem'
                });
                return false;
            }

            var out = JSON.parse(body);
            if (out.code != 0) {
                log.error(err, '[CRON][Antpool][Account] Error response('+out.code+'): '+out.message);
                sendEmailLog(EmailTemplate.LOG, {
                    message: '[CRON][Antpool][Account] Error response('+out.code+'): '+out.message
                });
                return false;
            }

            // Add to database
            let obj = {
                earn24: out.data.earn24Hours,
                earnTot: out.data.earnTotal,
                paidOut: out.data.paidOut,
                balance: out.data.balance,
                createdAt: new Date()
            };

            // Insert into database
            let insert = await this.table.insert(obj).run();

            if(insert) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

}

/**
 * Exports
 */
export {Antpool};
```

What I get is only error which have problem with await.

```
SyntaxError: .../antpool.js: Unexpected token (59:22)

            // Insert into database
            let insert = await this.table.insert(obj).run();
```

I am thinking what can be solution for accept the await. Is it little weird because in other parts of code await works well.
Not sure what the problem exactly is, but spent about two days finding the issue.

I am calling scripts with:

```
/**
 * Automatically hook babel into all node requires.
 */
require('babel/register')({
    optional: ['es7.asyncFunctions', 'es7.classProperties', 'es7.decorators']
});

/**
 * Start application worker.
 */
require('./src/worker');
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You are using await inside the function "function (err, httpResponse, body)" that is not signed as async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `await` can be used only in functions that are marked as `async`. Function in which you are trying to use `await`:

> `, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
>   ...`

is not marked as `async` and therefore it can't be compiled.

More info: [MDN article on async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Next problem came: execute: _cronsAntpool2['default'].account('btc') Cannot read property 'account' of undefined This seems problem somewhere hapi-cron-job and combination with: execute: Antpool.account('btc')

Comment: That seems to be something unrelated to the code you posted. However, it seems to be some issue with asynchronous callback of some function. When you realize which function gets called you'll probably realize that it's `this` is set to `undefined`. Then you need to find place where you pass that callback and bind it to some concrete object with `.bind(concreteObject)`

More on `.bind()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind